# Can't align text on the left on CSS

Tags: html, css, alignment

The text that is in the two boxes needs to be aligned on the left. However, even when I change "center" to "left" on the CSS code, it doesn't make a difference. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3D8Tq/)

```
    @charset "utf-8";

.box
{
    width: 560px;
    background-color:#CCC;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    color:#000;
    text-align:center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-top:15px;
    font-size:24px;
}
.boxbot
{
    width: 560px;
    background-color:#CCC;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    text-align:center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-top:3px;
    font-size:16px;
}
.boxyoutube
{
    width: 560px;
    height: 345px;
    background-color:#CCC;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    text-align:center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-top:3px;
    font-size:16px;
}
.boxbot2
{
    width: 560px;
    background-color:#CCC;
    text-align:center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-top:3px;
    font-size:16px;
}
.submit
{
    width: 560px;
    background-color:#CCC;
    text-align:left;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-top:3px;
    font-size:16px;
}
body
{
    alignment-adjust:central;
    background-color:#CCC;
}
select{
    width:auto;}
#wrapper
{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the alignment from these two classes `#wrapper` and `.boxbot2`

```
#wrapper
{
    text-align:center; -- remove it
}

.boxbot2
{
    width: 560px;
    background-color:#CCC;
    text-align:center;  -- remove it
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-top:3px;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3D8Tq/2/)

Comment: When i remove the alignment from .boxbot2 and #wrapper, nothing seems to happen :/

Comment: really?? did you check my fiddle. Is something wrong with that?

Comment: it works on your fiddle but when i edit the CSS on my website, there seems to be no difference :/ Is there any way you could help me with teamviewer?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `text-align` in your `#wrapper` declaration was set to `center`

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/3D8Tq/1/

I just removed the `text-align` from wrapper, seems to work fine